# Binding data to 5 different textbox in a linear layout

Tags: android, binding

I have obtained the xml response after parsing the web response and here it is

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <Restaurant_ID>1705</Restaurant_ID>
    <restaurant_name>1947</restaurant_name>
    <address>296, Ram Towers, 100 Feet Ring Road, Banashankari, Bangalore</address>
    <costoftwo>Approx Rs. 600 for two (without alcohol)</costoftwo>
    <rating>3.3</rating>
    <timings>11 AM to 11 PM</timings>
    <Phone>08026791213</Phone>
    <Location_ID>34</Location_ID>
    <Location_name>Banashankari</Location_name>
    <city_ID>1</city_ID>
    <city_name>Bangalore</city_name>
    <Cuisine_ID>8</Cuisine_ID>
    <Cuisine_name>North Indian</Cuisine_name>

  </Table>
```

and i have a XML layout to which i need to bind the above response. my Xml layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

  <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:background="@color/headerbgcolor"
      android:weightSum="1.0" 
      >  

     <Button
            android:id="@+id/restaurant_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:onClick="finishActivity"
            android:text="@string/back" />

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/restauran_details" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/restaurant_home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:text="@string/home" />
     </LinearLayout>

  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      >

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/Refresh"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="left"
          android:text="@string/refresh" />
  </RelativeLayout>

  <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:weightSum="1">

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/Restaurant_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="@string/restaurant_name" 
        />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/Restaurant_add"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="@string/restaurant_address" 
         />
     </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/Restaurant_rating"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/restaurant_rating"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"  />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/Restaurant_timings"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/restaurant_timings" 
        android:layout_weight="0.1"  />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/Restaurant_cstfortwo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cost_for_two" 
        android:layout_weight="0.1" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/Restaurant_cuisine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/restaurant_cuisine" 
        android:layout_weight="0.1" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/Restaurant_location"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/restaurant_location" 
        android:layout_weight="0.1" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/Restaurant_city"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/restaurant_city" 
        android:layout_weight="0.1" />

</LinearLayout>

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/Restaurant_phone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="@string/restaurant_phone"
        />

     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/footerimage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#808000"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_bg_cuisine" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

And i dont know whether it's good or not, but i am using customadapter to bind. Here is my customadapter.

```
public class CustomAdapterforRestaurant extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Item> mlist = null;
    private Context mcontext;
    private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;

    public CustomAdapterforRestaurant(Context context, List<Item> lstresponse) {
        mlist = lstresponse;
        mcontext = context;
        l_Inflater = (LayoutInflater) mcontext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewHolderforcities holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurantdetails, null);
            holder = new ViewHolderforcities(convertView);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolderforcities) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.restaurant_location.setText(mlist.get(position).getLocation_name());
        holder.restaurant_name.setText(mlist.get(position).getRestaurant_name());
        holder.restaurant_add.setText(mlist.get(position).getAddress());
        holder.restaurant_rating.setText(mlist.get(position).getRating());
        holder.restaurant_timings.setText(mlist.get(position).getTimings());
        holder.restaurant_cstfortwo.setText(mlist.get(position).getCostoftwo());
        holder.restaurant_cuisine.setText(mlist.get(position).getCuisine_name());
        holder.restaurant_city.setText(mlist.get(position).getCity_name());
        holder.restaurant_phone.setText(mlist.get(position).getPhone());


        return convertView;
    }



    class ViewHolderforcities {

        TextView restaurant_name,restaurant_add,restaurant_rating,restaurant_timings,
        restaurant_cstfortwo,restaurant_cuisine,restaurant_location,restaurant_city,
        restaurant_phone;

        public ViewHolderforcities(View base)

        {
            restaurant_name = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.Restaurant_name);
            restaurant_add = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.Restaurant_add);
            restaurant_rating = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.Restaurant_rating);
            restaurant_timings = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.Restaurant_timings);
            restaurant_cstfortwo = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.Restaurant_cstfortwo);
            restaurant_cuisine = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.Restaurant_cuisine);
            restaurant_location = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.Restaurant_location);
            restaurant_city = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.Restaurant_city);
            restaurant_phone = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.Restaurant_phone);
        }

    }
```

Can some 1 please explain me how will i bind the data to it.

Thanks 
Ramu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse this XML using one of the available XML parsers (The core android reference is http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html). Once you have got the information from the xml, You fill in the textViews programaticly using the `textView.setText("text")` method.

Comment: I am using sax parser for parsing and i am getting in list item. but it contains huge data. how will i bind only data i required?

Comment: if you are parsing the XML into an object (lets say Restaurant object in your case). then there should be any problem to get the data you want.

Comment: i am new to this, can you explain me bit clearly. i am going through Neil's link... but still i didnt get the proper idea how to do

Comment: do you have many "Table" objects in the "NewDataSet" you are receiving? if yes have you build a Restaurant/Table object that represents the received data?

Comment: yes i have many table details.. yea i have build an response data object

Comment: I just saw your code, your Adapter looks fine, the only problem is are you parsing correctly the XML items into your list.